# Is there way to share *.json file via Intent or something else?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin

In my app I need to share *.json file to other app (messenger, google disk, etc). How can I do this via Intent or something else?

But when I trying to do this via Intent, I have some problems.

```
override fun shareBackupData(path: String) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(path)
        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        shareIntent.type = "*/*"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose"))
    }
```

When I run this code, I choose app to share and then I see toast "unsupported attachment"

Comment: Try to add `shareIntent.type=("text/plain")` instead, also make sure the path is correct.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS path example - /storage/emulated/0/FinBall/backup/FinBallFrom 26.03.2019-13:48:20.json
still doesn't work

Comment: What api are you using?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS for what?

Comment: "path example" -- that is not a valid `Uri`. That is a filesystem path. A `Uri` has a scheme, like `file` or `content` or `http` or `https`. If you wish to make a file available to other apps, use `FileProvider` [as Skizo describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55356905/115145).

Comment: @DmytroMelnyk if it worked mark my answer as a correct and upvote it, and also feel free to post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems with this and I found this [article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) where it recommends us to use [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).

What it does is :

> FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.

I recommend you to take a look to the article and also if you want code, take a look at this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the file as ExtrtaStream the following code is sharing image file you can change it to your json file

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg");//change it with your file
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: I try this earlier, no result